# Show that a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if $X^\Bbb N$ is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

> Show that a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if $X^\Bbb N$ is locally compact.

Assume that $X$ is compact, then for every open cover of $X$ there exists a finite subcover. To show that $X^\Bbb N$ I need to show that for any $f \in X^\Bbb N$ there exists a neighborhood $U_f$ such that $\overline{U_f}$ is compact.

I think that $X^\Bbb N$ has the product topology so instead of working with open sets I think I should be working with the basic open sets.

If $U_f$ is any neighborhood of $f \in X^\Bbb N$, then there exists a basic open set $B=\bigcap_{n \in F} \pi_n^{-1}(V_n)$ (where $F \subset \Bbb N$ is finite) such that $$f \in B \subset U_f$$

Can I show that $\overline{B}$ is compact to conclude the result? If so then I would need to show that $\overline{\bigcap_{n \in F} \pi_n^{-1}(V_n)}$ is compact or equivalently that $\overline{\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n}$ where $V_n \ne X$ for only finitely many $n$.

I know that the latter gives me something as $$\overline{\prod_{n \in \Bbb N} V_n} = \prod_{n \in \Bbb N} \overline{V_n}$$ but I cannot figure out how to use the data that $X$ is compact in the proof. I think that I can find an open set in the finite cover of $X$ for every $V_n$?

Comment: If $X$ is compact then any product space of $X$ is compact, thus locally compact

Comment: As for the reverse direction, I'm not convinced this is true. I think we should expect it to be true if $X$ is a first countable space, maybe, or to prove countable compactness

Comment: If $T$ is a compact subset of $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ with nonempty interior, almost any of the coordinate projections $T \rightarrow X$ are onto, making $X$ compact. No?

Comment: Do you need the product topology? $X^{\mathbb N}$ can be viewed as the set of countable sequences in $X$.

Comment: Does "compact" include Hausdorff?

Comment: @JohnDouma the product topology is not "needed", it is inside the question when asking about a topological property for $X^{\mathbb N}.$ And we know that $X^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of infinite sequences of elements of $X,$ so what for do you mention it?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think Hausdorff is not needed in the comments 1 and 3 (from FShrike and Aphelli), which completely answer the question.

Comment: @Aphelli Very nice! That shows why my concern about countability isn’t important. The idea isn’t nets, but rather to have enough coordinates that deletion of finitely many always leaves some spaces left

Comment: @AnneBauval If "Hausdorff" is not required, it depends on the definition of "locally compact" whether $X^\mathbb N$ is locally compact. If "locally compact" means that each point has a basis of compact neighborhoods, then it is wrong.

Comment: @PaulFrost I agree. I took for "locally compact" the [definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) (like FShrike, I think): every point has a compact neighborhood.

Comment: @AnneBauval So the OP should answer my question and (for the non-Hausdorff case) give us the definition of "locally compact".

Comment: What is the source of your question? An exercise in  a textbook?